# How to fetch each array?

Tags: php, arrays

My array o/p is

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [valueIdentifier] => LOGIN [valueMask] => LOGIN_FIELD)
 [1] => Array ( [valueIdentifier] => PASSWORD [valueMask] => LOGIN_FIELD [fieldType] .
```

I want to each array so i tried this

```
  foreach($myArray as $users){
       foreach($users as $user){
           echo $x=$user['valueIdentifier'];
       }
  }
```

I got the output: LOGINPASSWORD. I want to get output LOGIN, PASSWORD SEPERATE. So i did this:

```
echo $x=$user[0]['valueIdentifier'];
echo $x=$user[1]['valueIdentifier'];
```

But i did not get the answer.

Comment: Check using, $user['valueIdentifier'][0], $user['valueIdentifier'][1]

Comment: i tried this:i got o/p LOPA

Comment: PHP version > 5.5.0 use `echo implode(',',array_column($your_array,'valueIdentifier'));` or for lower versions `echo implode(',',array_map(function($v){ return $v['valueIdentifier'];},$your_array));`

Comment: The code as shown right now shouldn't actually work. But just put a new line or something like this in between, e.g. `echo $user[0]['valueIdentifier'] . PHP_EOL;` or in the browser use `<br />` instead

Answer (score 0):

Concat comma on nested foreach; it will show you what you want

```
foreach($myArray as $users){
   foreach($users as $user){

       echo $user['valueIdentifier'].',';
   }
}
```

Output would be :

```
LOGIN,PASSWORD,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
        $arr_final = array();

        $arr = array (
                        0 => array (
                                        'valueIdentifier' => 'LOGIN',
                                        'valueMask' => 'LOGIN_FIELD'
                                    ),
                        1 => array (
                                        'valueIdentifier' => 'PASSWORD',
                                        'valueMask' => 'LOGIN_FIELD'
                                    )
                    );
        /* SCENARIO 1 */
        foreach( $arr as $key_arr => $value_arr )
            {
                $arr_final[] = $value_arr['valueIdentifier'];
            }

        if(!empty($arr_final))
            echo implode(', ', $arr_final);

        /* SCENARIO 2 */
        echo "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
        echo $arr[0]['valueIdentifier'];
        echo $arr[1]['valueIdentifier'];

        exit();

    ?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!